# Understanding how Relationships are done in Realm Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, realm, relationship

I'm having a hard time understanding how to create objects that relate to each other in a `one-to-many` relation.

Is there a special sequence in which the data needs to be entered? In other words, does the owner and the items need to be enter at the same time?

Here is what I'm trying to do to have a better understanding.

I have a simple shoppingList-like app where a list can have many items. What I want is to `first` give the user the ability to enter individual items into a `UITableView` and then if the user wants to save the data, he then would create a `new list` but I'm not sure how or when to enter the data.

Here is the code I have which persists the items in `Realm` and shows the them in the table.

#### ShoppingList Class

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

class ShoppingList: Object{
    dynamic var listName = ""
    var itemList = List<Item>()
}
```

#### Item Class

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

class Item:Object {

    dynamic var productName: String = ""
}
```

#### Main ViewController

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var inputProductName: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var inputListName: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var itemsTable: UITableView!

    var item:Item? 
    var realm:Realm?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        realm = try! Realm()
    }

    @IBAction func newItem(_ sender: Any) {
        item = Item()
        item?.productName = inputProductName.text!

        try! realm?.write {
            realm?.add(item!)
        }

        itemsTable.reloadData()
        inputProductName.text = “” // clear inputField
    }

    /// TABLE
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        let items = realm?.objects(Item.self)
        return (items?.count)!
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell()
        let items = realm?.objects(Item.self)[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = items?.productName
        return cell
    }
}
```

#### TableView

[image]

How Can I create a list with the items show in the table?

Comment: [This might help](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/4816#issuecomment-291688421)

Comment: @EpicPandaForce - Thank you for the link, even though I did find what I was looking for there it opened up my mind and I now have a better understand, I think I was trying to use `Realm` in a way that it was not intended to. Sorry but I'm new to databases in general. Thanks.